# "Errno2" py2exe, my script cant be found

Tags: python, py2exe

I am trying to use py2exe but it won't find the python script that I specified in the setup.py.

yes they are in the same directory.

i get this message;

```
C:\Users\11>c:\users\11\desktop\setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pygame.py'
```

Comment: Did you write a script called pygame.py?  Or are you trying to use the pygame 3rd party module?

Comment: The script is called pygame.py yes

Comment: It can't find that file.  Either specify a relative path, or make sure it's in the current directory.  Normally I'd call the script something more along the lines of `python setup.py py2exe` from within the same directory as setup.py.

Comment: I tried calling the script as you said, but now i get the same 'Errno 2' error, but now it can't find the 'setup.py' file

Comment: You're in the wrong directory then